# How to upload files in Django and save them in a different location depending on the format? (jpeg and doc)

Tags: django, file-upload

How to upload files in Django and **save them (and take other actions in the signal - `post_save`) in a different location depending on the format**? (jpeg and doc)

```
def upload(request):
    user = request.user
    upload_form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            my_model = upload_form.save(commit=False)
            my_model.user = user
            my_model.save()
```

models:

```
class FileStore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    standard = models.FileField(upload_to="standard")
    after_operation = models.FileField(upload_to="after_ocr",blank=True, null=True)
```

signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FileStore)
def my_handler(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        text= image_to_string(Image.open(instance.standard))
        ...
        instance.after_operation = File(text_file)
        instance.save()
```

I want if file is `.doc` or `.pdf` save only in `standard` field and if file is `.jpeg` or `.png` I need run my signal function.

Comment: Does your file belongs to a model where it has a `upload_to` attribute or is just a randome file upload?

Comment: My files belongs to a model where is `upload_to`

Comment: So you don't want to stick to that folder am I right? Because you want to save them in different folder?

Comment: @PauloBu I updated my question. I hope now is clear. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see the signal now, you have to figure out where is stored the `request.FILES` dict or the file uploaded there and apply something from my answer

Comment: Also consider doing this from the view instead of the signal, maybe it is clearer that way.

Answer (score 5):

For instance, you can retrieve the uploaded file by accessing the `request.FILES` dictionary like this:

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
```

`uploaded_file` is now of type `UploadedFile` which means you can get info about the file like this:

```
# name of the file, ie: my_file.txt
filename = uploaded_file.name
# file extension (get the las 4 chars)
file_ext = filename[-4:]
# handle file extension
if file_ext == '.jpg':
    # do something for jpegs
if file_ext == '.doc':
    # do something for docs
```

So now, for saving it you may try this, I haven't prove it yet:

```
# f is the UploadedFile
model_file = File(f)
model_file.save('path/to/wherever.ext', f.readlines(), true)
```

I hope this helps! This may not work out of the box but I hope it bring some light to the problem. Try to look at the docs: [django files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/) and [django uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/). This topic is very well documented.

Good luck!